# SQL - don't include current week's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have some weekly code that when run I don't want it to include the current week's data. The dates are slightly odd because it is a financial calendar.

```
|  Date     | Week  | Year|
---------------------------
|30-12-2017 |  52   | 2017|
|31-12-2017 |   1   | 2018|
|01-01-2018 |   1   | 2018|
```

I've looked at

```
where week = datepart(ww, date) -1 
and year = datepart(yyyy, date)
```

but this doesn't work at the end of the year when the year ticks over and week 1 minus 1 does not equal week 52

Comment: what do u want to exclude in week1 of 2018 ?

Comment: I am wondering which calendar that allows Sunday 2017-12-31 to be week 1. I tried to find it using google but failed. Do you have those 3 columns in your local calendar table(Date, Week, Year) ?

Comment: What is your input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare dates. `dateadd(ww, datediff(ww,0,getdate()), 0)` will get first day of week. So your query should look like

```
where
    dateColumn < dateadd(ww, datediff(ww,0,getdate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
where week = datepart(ww, dateadd(week, -1, getdate()) and
      year = datepart(yyyy, dateadd(week, -1, getdate())
```

I'm not sure what `date` is in your code.  `getdate()` is for the current date.  Of course, any other date could be substituted to get the previous week.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want such clause:

```
where (year < datepart(yyyy, getdate())) or
      (week < datepart(ww, getdate()) and
       year = datepart(yyyy, getdate()))
```

The logic is: take all records where `year` is less than current year (data from past years), also take records from current year, but where week number is less than current week.